# Ubuntu Server installed in error/want Gnome

Tags: 14.04, server

I made an error in installing Ubuntu Gnome. I had the wrong image and installed Ubuntu Server 14.04. I tried the following commands to add Ubuntu Gnome:

- sudo apt-get update (had several errors)
- sudo apt-get install gnome (more errors)
- sudo tasksel (opened option menu, but wouldn't execute any choices)

Is there a way to uninstall Ubuntu Server 14.04 and install Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 instead? Should I be able to do so from BIOS with a bootable USB?